# How to display forecasting results by using the autolayer function in R

Tags: forecasting

Im trying to reproduce the results from this book https://otexts.com/fpp2/.

```
library(fpp2)
    beer2 <- window(ausbeer,start=1992,end=c(2007,4))
    beerfit1 <- meanf(beer2,h=10)
    beerfit2 <- rwf(beer2,h=10)
    beerfit3 <- snaive(beer2,h=10)
    autoplot(window(ausbeer, start=1992)) +
    autolayer(beerfit1, series="Mean", PI=FALSE) +
    autolayer(beerfit2, series="Naïve", PI=FALSE) +
    autolayer(beerfit3, series="Seasonal naïve", PI=FALSE) +
    xlab("Year") + ylab("Megalitres") +
    ggtitle("Forecasts for quarterly beer production") +
    guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Forecast"))
```

When running the code above I get the following error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , c("alpha", "colour", "size",
> "linetype")) :    undefined columns selected

Does anyone know how to fix it?

beer2 is a time series [1:64] from 1992 to 2008, and beerfit1-3 is a list of 11.

I have tried to run the code above, but it does not work.

Comment: The code works for me without error. Try running it an fresh R session. Perhaps you have loaded packages that are interfering.